DuckDB InvalidInputException counting rows via PyArrow
I'm using DuckDB and PyArrow to analyze the NYC taxi dataset, available from s3://ursa-labs-taxi-data as described here.
This is a 37GB dataset of NYC taxi trip data from Jan 2009 through June 2019, arranged thus:
├───2009
│   ├───01
│   │   └── data.parquet
│   ├───02
│   │   └── data.parquet
│   ├───03
│   │   └── data.parquet
...
├───2019
│   ├───04
│   │   └── data.parquet
│   ├───05
│   │   └── data.parquet
│   ├───06
│   │   └── data.parquet

┌────────────────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│    column_name     │ column_type │  null    │
│      varchar       │   varchar   │ varchar  │
├────────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┤
│ vendor_id          │ VARCHAR     │ YES      │
│ pickup_at          │ TIMESTAMP   │ YES      │
│ dropoff_at         │ TIMESTAMP   │ YES      │
│ passenger_count    │ TINYINT     │ YES      │
│ trip_distance      │ FLOAT       │ YES      │
│ pickup_longitude   │ FLOAT       │ YES      │
│ pickup_latitude    │ FLOAT       │ YES      │
│ rate_code_id       │ INTEGER     │ YES      │
│ store_and_fwd_flag │ VARCHAR     │ YES      │
│ dropoff_longitude  │ FLOAT       │ YES      │
│ dropoff_latitude   │ FLOAT       │ YES      │
│ payment_type       │ VARCHAR     │ YES      │
│ fare_amount        │ FLOAT       │ YES      │
│ extra              │ FLOAT       │ YES      │
│ mta_tax            │ FLOAT       │ YES      │
│ tip_amount         │ FLOAT       │ YES      │
│ tolls_amount       │ FLOAT       │ YES      │
│ total_amount       │ FLOAT       │ YES      │
├────────────────────┴─────────────┴──────────┘


My Python code looks like:
import duckdb
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import time

nyc_dataset = ds.dataset('C:\\data\\nyc-taxi\\', partitioning=["year", "month"])
con = duckdb.connect()

start = time.time()
query = con.execute("select count(*) from nyc_dataset") # *** the query ***
results = query.fetchall()
end = time.time()

for x in results:
    print(x)
print()
print(f'[Query took {end - start:.2f}s]')

This produces the error:
> python duckdb-arrow.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Storage\Code\untracked\duck-arrow\nyc-arrow2.py", line 9, in <module>
    query = con.execute("select count(*) from nyc_dataset")
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
duckdb.duckdb.InvalidInputException: Invalid Input Error: arrow_scan: get_next failed(): NotImplemented: Unsupported cast from string to null using function cast_null

However, if I change the query to select count(*) from nyc_dataset where year > 2008 then things do work. And yet, because the dataset is from Jan 2009 - Jun 2019, exactly the same amount of data appears to be processed.
> python duckdb-arrow.py
(1547741381,)

[Query took 4.47s]

Strangely, the query select count(vendor_id) from nyc_dataset also works and produces the same result, although it takes almost 13s for the query to complete.
I'm using Python 3.12.2 and my venv has these dependencies:
duckdb==1.1.1
numpy==2.1.2
pyarrow==17.0.0

I'm new to using Arrow with DuckDB so I'm confused about why this is happening. Would anyone please be able to point me towards what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!
